# Problem with connection to the Oracle datavase in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle18c

I have a problem with connection to the database.
I can connect via sqldeveloper but if I try to connect in ASP.NET Core MVC via Oracle Database (ODP.NET, Managed Driver) I get this error:
[Error img here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NG89P.png) 
Do you have any idea why I can't connect?
Thank you for your response.

Comment: I've tried to make it work according to other solutions that I found on the Internet but it failed

Comment: your error message is hiding the most important part of your connection properties - the service name. please share your sql developer connection properties and your asp.net connection properties

Comment: Thanks to your comment I realize where was my mistake. I couldn't connect to school database via "Service name" but only with "SID".